# How to batch rename files in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, batch, batch-rename

I have the bunch of files that have names like MOV001.mpg, MOV002.mpg etc. They all have different date-time.

How can I rename them so they turn into 2012 08 05  13 45 33  MOV001.mpg, 2012 09 02  23 45 07  MOV002.mpg etc.?

In other words, how can I extract the date and time information from the files I rename?

Thank you much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
for f in *.mpg; do
  mv "$f" "$(stat -f "%m" -t "%Y %m %d %H %M %S" "$f") $f"
done
```

`stat -f "%m"` should produce the last modified date of the file, `-t "%Y %m %d %H %M %S"` should format the date according to your requirements.

Comment: Thank you. Helped when using `stat -f "%Sm"` instead of `stat -f "%m"`

Answer (score 1):

The original question specifies that the resultant files also end with a file extension. To do this in a portable fashion, in bash, grab the extension from the `/path/to/file.ext` with `${f##*.}` built-in, resulting in a one-liner of:

```
for f in *.FOO; do mv "$f" "$( /usr/bin/stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S" ).${f##*.}" ; done
```

and a code block of

```
for f in *.FOO ; do
    mv "$f" "$( /usr/bin/stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S" ).${f##*.}"
done
```

so when you change FOO (eg from *.mpg to *.png) the output filenames are sane.