# Change date scheme of file name with script

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I have about 8 years of video files on a server for my work. We want to change the files' date schemes from MMDDYY to YYMMDD for organizational purposes. The filename structure is MMDDYY_Filename.xxx. What would be the best way to do this? I was thinking of an automator/applescript workflow to rearrange the first 6 characters of a filename to make it work, but I'm not sure how to make it happen. Any ideas?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/480726/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me the easiest way to do this is use Automator (with Applescript) to strip off the first 6 or 8 characters (depending on your existing date format: "131016" or "20131016")…then run the Rename Finder Items workflow, like this:

Automator Workflow:

(Run Applescript)

on run {input, parameters}

```
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with f in (choose file with multiple selections allowed)
        set name of f to text 6 thru -1 of (get name of f)
    end repeat
end tell
return input
```

end run

(Rename Finder Items - - Add Date or Time with following parameters:)

Date/Time: Created          Format: Year Month Day
Where: Before Name       Separator: None
Separator:   Underscore

(Example: 20131016+_Item Name.xxx)

If it's NOT your intention to have the "20" at the beginning, then run another Applescript like the one above to trim off the first two characters again, since this Automator item automatically adds the "20."

Got the original script from here:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20134/how-can-i-trim-the-first-3-characters-in-file-name-with-applescript

Answer (score 0):

If all files are in the same directory, you can run something like this in Terminal:

```
cd directory; for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f:4:2}${f:0:4}${f:6}"; done
```

If the files are in different directories:

```
find directory -name \*.xxx | while read f; do
  f2=${f##*/}
  mv "$f" "${f%/*}/${f2:4:2}${f2:0:4}${f2:6}"
done
```